# Google+ Interactive post not working?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-plus

i want to use Google+ interactive post for my webpage. I implemented this function according to the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive). Everything works fine. But if the user wants to select people or circles, with whom he wants to share the post pops up an error message "Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)". Console shows error "Object init is not defined" in file picker.js on Google servers. I created empty page only with Google+ interactive post functionality (like in [this presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Iw28jWtAY)) but with same results.

Doing I am something wrong? Or this error is on google side?

It is another way to share the post with a predefined message on G+?

Thanks for reply and sorry for my bad english.

Code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE thml>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<button
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="http://www.mediasolution.cz"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/"
  data-clientid="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Message for friends."
  data-calltoactionlabel="REGISTER"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://www.mediasolution.cz"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/">
  Share
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with multiple different browsers and multiple different Google accounts?

Comment: Yes, i try 2 Google accounts and all main browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) with same result.

Comment: Does the [invite your friends](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#button_design) example work for you? Do you have a hosted test case we can try?

Comment: Yes invite your friends works, but I can not find a difference. I found several other non-functional sites (example: [mashable](http://mashable.com/2014/07/29/this-app-lets-you-ask-a-doctor-a-question/)). Here is my [sample app](http://work4.mediasolution.cz/google-interactive-post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is broken period. I have not found a single working live implementation anywhere. They all do the same thing. The only place it is configured to work is at "https://developers.google.com". If you inspect the dom to the iframe you can launch it directly. If you change that origin to your own site it will fail.

If ANYONE cares about this... please star or comment on the google dev bug report for it and maybe it'll get fixed.

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=718&q=type%3DDefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars